# How to download latest build from buildfarm

Tags: opencv, build, buildbot, buildfarm

It is probably a noob question but I want to ask about a **BuildFarm**.
For example, I went to OpenCV's official site and found a link to **BuildFarm**. 
http://build.opencv.org/#/summary/

It has listings of all the latest builds by BuildBot on various platforms. I want to download the latest build from there but couldn't find a link to any.

Is **BuildFarm** supposed to provide the links to latest builds ? Is it safe to download those builds?
If anyone knows how to download from the above farm, please help me.

Comment: the build farm is used to run unit tests on [github pull requests](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute#Testing-and-merging-of-pull-requests).

Comment: @berak : Can I download the builds?

Comment: once , the maintainer(e.g. vpisarev) deems an addition worthwile (and the buildbot proved, that it won't do any harm), it ends up in the respective git branch. in other words: use git to update your local codebase, pull regularily, and you're up-to-date

Comment: @berak : That is the whole point. I am aware that it ends up in the master branch. I even downloaded the master-source. The thing is - I tried to build OpenCV but apparently due to a bug or something or my incompetency I failed to build opencv_world. Moreover I cannot build with many options ticked(example TBB on). Better if somebody provide with latest build and BuildBot does that, so I was hoping I could get my hands on one of those. I am currently using OpenCV3.0.0 Beta from site with none of the bug fixes are incorporated in the build.